# Error: invalid bucket size spec: undefined

Tags: zenbot

```html
./zenbot.sh trade --manual
node-telegram-bot-api deprecated Automatic enabling of cancellation of promises is deprecated.
In the future, you will have to enable it yourself.
See https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/319. module.js:635:30
/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/timebucket/lib/bucket-size.js:15
  if (!match) throw new Error('invalid bucket size spec: ' + spec);
              ^

Error: invalid bucket size spec: undefined
    at BucketSize.parse (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/timebucket/lib/bucket-size.js:15:21)
    at new BucketSize (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/timebucket/lib/bucket-size.js:5:21)
    at Bucket.resize (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/timebucket/lib/bucket.js:30:14)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/home/local/zenbot/commands/trade.js:312:32)
    at Command.listener (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Command.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Command.parseArgs (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/commander/index.js:653:12)
    at Command.parse (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/commander/index.js:475:21)
    at /home/local/zenbot/zenbot.js:39:11
    at /home/local/zenbot/boot.js:24:7
    at f (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/glob/glob.js:151:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Glob.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Glob._finish (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/glob/glob.js:197:8)
    at done (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/glob/glob.js:182:14)
    at Glob._processGlobStar2 (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/glob/glob.js:637:12)
    at /home/local/zenbot/node_modules/glob/glob.js:626:10
    at RES (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/inflight/inflight.js:31:16)
    at f (/home/local/zenbot/nodemodules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at lstatcb (/home/local/zenbot/node_modules/glob/glob.js:519:7)
```

I have no idea what could be causing this as I'm pretty sure I have followed the instructions to a T.
Trying to use this to manually trade on GDAX, i have my api keys on the conf.
I'm on windows 10 using "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows".

Comment: I think some recent PR's have resolved this issue, please pull latest and try again.

Answer (score 0):

According to [#938](https://github.com/DeviaVir/zenbot/issues/938) issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/DeviaVir/zenbot/issues/938), this has been fixed in [#926](https://github.com/DeviaVir/zenbot/pull/926) and [#940](https://github.com/DeviaVir/zenbot/pull/940) pull requests.

So please consider upgrading your Zenbot. Otherwise raise [a new issue](https://github.com/DeviaVir/zenbot/issues).